# How to convert field values from lower case to upper case in ArcGIS 10.1?

Tags: python, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, vbscript

Using the Field Calculator in ArcGIS 10.1, I am able convert the first letter in a value from lower case to upper case. How do you convert the entire value to upper case, though?  I can't seem to locate a VBScript for it.

For example, I want to convert *small* to *SMALL*.

Comment: Use Python parser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use UCase

```
UCase( [fieldName] )
```

Answer (score 18):

Another alternative using Python would be:

```
!fieldname!.upper()
```

as described in the online help [Calculate Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004s000000) examples.

Comment: Why do they need to change the scripting where there is more room for errors. Why not just keep VBScripting for the latest Arc versions?

Comment: +1 it would be best for everyone to wean themselves off vbscript and move onto python asap.

Comment: There is no mention of vbscript being deprecated in Desktop (yet), but if you read into the long term future of vbscript (on Desktop) based upon the [ArcGIS Server deprecation plan](http://downloads2.esri.com/support/TechArticles/ArcGIS10and101Deprecation_Plan.pdf), can it be too far off?  _ArcGIS 10.1 for Server no longer supports VBScript or JScript expressions **on Linux**. [...] Python scripting will be added as a replacement for these scripting languages and ArcGIS Desktop will support authoring Python scripts in areas where VBScript and JScript are presently used._

Comment: @RyanDalton -- The fact that Google is the best place to go to find this answer when I spent a good 30 minutes (At ESRI Technical Support)[https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011159] trying to find this and only came up with the parallel answer **!Existing Field!.title()** -- Technically it may be _Technical Support_ but practically it's just frustrating to use. -- But yes, thankfully they are moving on to Python and placing VB in the same bin as [AML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARC_Macro_Language)

Comment: In ArcGIS 10.6 the Python version was like this: `[FIELDNAME].upper()` to convert all lower cases to upper cases